# Cannot merge two DataFrames in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, merge

I've been trying to append 1 DataFrame to another DF in Scala. The append operation in this case is simply adding a new column of the same size to the existing column - no key matching is involved. Both DataFrames are of the same shape (5 rows and 1 column only).

```
scala> val coefficients = lrModel.coefficients.toArray.toSeq.toDF("coefficients")
coefficients: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [coefficients: double]

scala> coefficients.show()
+--------------------+
|        coefficients|
+--------------------+
|   -59525.0697785032|
|   6957.836000531959|
|   314.2998010755629|
|-0.37884289844065666|
|  -1758.154438149325|
+--------------------+
scala> val tvalues = trainingSummary.tValues.toArray.drop(1).toSeq.toDF("t-values")
tvalues: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [t-values: double]

scala> tvalues.show()
+-------------------+
|           t-values|
+-------------------+
| 1.8267249911295418|
| 100.35507390273406|
| -8.768588605222108|
|-0.4656738230173362|
|  10.48091833711012|
+-------------------+
```

The `join()` function runs and I can even get the schema, but when I want to display all values of the new DF I'm getting the error:

```
scala> val outputModelDF1 = coefficients.join(tvalues)
outputModelDF1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [coefficients: double, t-values: double]
scala> outputModelDF1.printSchema()
root
 |-- coefficients: double (nullable = false)
 |-- t-values: double (nullable = false)

scala> outputModelDF1.show()
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Detected cartesian product for INNER join between logical plans
Project [value#359 AS coefficients#361]
+- LocalRelation [value#359]
and
Project [value#368 AS t-values#370]
+- LocalRelation [value#368]
Join condition is missing or trivial.
Use the CROSS JOIN syntax to allow cartesian products between these relations.;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.CheckCartesianProducts$$anonfun$apply$20.applyOrElse(Optimizer.scala:1080)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.CheckCartesianProducts$$anonfun$apply$20.applyOrElse(Optimizer.scala:1077)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:267)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:267)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:266)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:256)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.CheckCartesianProducts.apply(Optimizer.scala:1077)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.CheckCartesianProducts.apply(Optimizer.scala:1062)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:85)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:82)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldl(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:57)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:66)
  at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foldLeft(WrappedArray.scala:35)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:82)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:74)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:74)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:84)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:80)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:89)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:89)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:2832)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2153)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2366)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:245)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:644)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:603)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:612)
  ... 52 elided
```

Any idea how to deal with it and how to simply merge these two DFs together?

UPDATE 1

I should have stated the desired format of the output that I want to achieve. Please see below:

```
    +--------------------+--------------------+
    |        coefficients|            t-values|
    +--------------------+--------------------+
    |   -59525.0697785032|  1.8267249911295418|
    |   6957.836000531959|  100.35507390273406|
    |   314.2998010755629|  -8.768588605222108|
    |-0.37884289844065666| -0.4656738230173362|
    |  -1758.154438149325|  -1758.154438149325|
    +--------------------+--------------------+
```

UPDATE 2

Unfortunately, the following approach using `withColumn()` didn't work.

```
scala> val outputModelDF1 = coefficients.withColumn("t-values", tvalues("t-values"))
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: resolved attribute(s) t-values#119 missing from coefficients#113 in operator !Project [coefficients#113, t-values#119 AS t-values#130];;
!Project [coefficients#113, t-values#119 AS t-values#130]
+- Project [value#111 AS coefficients#113]
   +- LocalRelation [value#111]

  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.failAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:39)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.failAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:91)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:347)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.checkAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:91)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:52)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:66)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$withPlan(Dataset.scala:2872)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.select(Dataset.scala:1153)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withColumn(Dataset.scala:1908)
  ... 52 elided
```

Comment: You're doing a SQL Cross join, not appending two columns together

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, I know, it's clear from the error message, but I don't want a crossJoin. Please see the update with the desired output above.

Comment: Look at the `withColumn` function

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks, you had a good idea. Leo C below showed the working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to create key columns in the dataframes for the `join` using `monotonicallyIncreasingId`:

```
val df1 = Seq(
  (-59525.0697785032), (6957.836000531959), (314.2998010755629), (-0.37884289844065666), (-1758.154438149325)
).toDF("coefficients")

val df2 = Seq(
  (1.8267249911295418), (100.35507390273406), (-8.768588605222108), (-0.4656738230173362), (10.48091833711012)
).toDF("t-values")

val df1R = df1.withColumn("rowid", monotonicallyIncreasingId)
val df2R = df2.withColumn("rowid", monotonicallyIncreasingId)

val dfJoined = df1R.join(df2R, Seq("rowid"))

dfJoined.show
+-----+--------------------+-------------------+
|rowid|        coefficients|           t-values|
+-----+--------------------+-------------------+
|    0|   -59525.0697785032| 1.8267249911295418|
|    1|   6957.836000531959| 100.35507390273406|
|    2|   314.2998010755629| -8.768588605222108|
|    3|-0.37884289844065666|-0.4656738230173362|
|    4|  -1758.154438149325|  10.48091833711012|
+-----+--------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I've accepted your solution. However, I still hope there is a nicer way of doing it. I find creating 2 additional DFs very inefficient. Any idea if Scala has anything similar to R's cbind() function?

Comment: @simtim, unfortunately I'm not aware of any equivalence of `R's cbind` in Spark using Scala.  You could consider converting the dataframes to RDDs, perform `zip` like `df1.rdd zip df2.rdd`, then convert the result back to dataframes.

Comment: I prefer to use withColumn() in this case rather than converting dataframes to RDDs and back. Of course, these DFs in my example are very small - I'm basically cleaning up the outputs of some ml algorithms, but I'm wondering how efficient it is to use withColumn() or zip approaches on large DFs. Surely, this must be slow and memory hungry.

Comment: You're right that `withColumn` isn't particularly cheap.  In your case, it would be best for the ML computation, if applicable, to leave row-identifying columns in the resultant dataframes.